Calling Fortran subroutine from Visual Studio C++
Sroll down to UPD0 please
I want to compile a fortran subroutine to windows
DLL and call it from Visual Studio C++.
It is a large subroutine from octave source code.
There is a good article
https://sites.northwestern.edu/wklee/2017/03/10/calling-fortran-code-from-c-on-visual-studio-2015/
But the problem is that dllwrap.exe utility is obsolete and it does not
working properly on my Windows OS.
I will explain how I created DLL using modern tools and the problem
which I can't solve.
First we need to compile Fortran procedure
gfortran -c cbesh.f -o cbesh.flib

Option -c means compile only do not link.
Then we calling linker and telling him to generate dll library
ld -shared --export-all-symbols --output-def cbesh.def cbesh.flib -o cbesh.dll

Now we have dll file. But we need also lib file to add it to our Visual studio.
lib.exe /MACHINE:x86 /def:cbesh.def

Now we have lib file and dll file.
We can add library to visual studio and call the subroutine from it.
I have tested this approach on a simple subroutine. It works.
The problem is that this large subroutine has calls to external functions.
Like CABS.
When I call linker ld.exe it gives errror:
ld: cbesh.flib:cbesh.f:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `cabsf'
Ok. So I need to add an external library which exeports this cabs functions.
I have checked that libgfotran exports _cabs with objdump.exe.
And cbhesh.flib also imports _cabs.
So I need to add libgfortran library to linker.
Here is command line
ld -shared -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Octave/Octave-8.3.0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/" -lgfortran --export-all-symbols --output-def "main_sub.def"  -o "main_sub.dll" "main_sub.flib"

But there is still error
ld: main_sub.main_sub:main_sub.f:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `cabsf'
main_sub is a simple fortran subroutine which was converted to dll
without errors but when i added CABS call to it the linking error occured.
I have added libgfortran to linker but it does not help.
How can i build this dll?
Thanks,
UPD0
OK. Let's simplify the story. I have managed today to
reproduce the problem with more simple example.
Without Visaul C++ envolved at all :)
Let's consider the simple fortran program
PROGRAM TEST
  use iso_c_binding
  COMPLEX X
  COMPLEX Y
  Y = CABS(X)
  END

I can compile it and link with one command
gfortran main.f -o main.exe

ok. no errors.
That means that my setup has _cabsf implementation.
But what if I want to compile and link in separate steps?
gfortran -c main.f -o main.o

OK. No errors. main.o object file generated.
Now linking:
ld main.o -o main.exe

BAD. 4 errors
ld: main.o:main.f:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `cabsf'
ld: main.o:main.f:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__main'
ld: main.o:main.f:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
ld: main.o:main.f:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'

Ok. Let's add -lgfortran library
ld main.o -o main.exe -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Octave/Octave-8.3.0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/" -lgfortran

Better. 2 errors
ld: main.o:main.f:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `cabsf'
ld: main.o:main.f:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__main'

The same problem as above. We can now forget about Visual C++.
There is a problem in fortran linking itself.
So I think that some adittionall libraries should be added to
ld.exe linker. libgfortran is not enough.
I have found on internet that gfortran is a frontend to gcc.
So it knows what libraries must be added to linkage and does it IMPLICITLY.
If i use gfortran to link *.o file I don't need to specify any libraries
EXPLICITLY.
gfortran main.o -o main.exe

OK. No errors.
gfortran adds libraries to linker IMPLICITLY.
So my question is the following.
What libraries I need to pass EXPLICITLY to ld.exe to link fortran object files?

Normally, one adds the library at the end of the link command.

Make sure the Fortran side is using the appropriate BIND directives, including anything necessary to get agreement with the C++ compiler on the exported routine name(s).  Note that you don't need a .lib file to call into a .dll from C or C++, you can also use the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress functions to get a function pointer to call (and there are some nice C++ features which will let you wrap all of this into a perfect forwarding template).

I have updated the question to simplify the story

One usually expects cabsf, which is not the Fortran intrinsic cabs, to be in libm. Why do you expect all runtime functions to be in libgfortran?

Why do you need to use ld directly and then worry about which runtime libraries to add, rather than use the compiler's driver which is designed to worry about that for you? If necessary, you can ask the compiler what it's doing and replicate, but sometimes you'll need one library which in another project you won't.

I need to link with ld.exe because i can't use gfortran for linking. I want to produce a dll but gfortran does not understand --export-all-symbols and --output-def. An i didn't found any manual on how to create DLL with gfortran linker. I will try to search tomorrow.

gfortran can pass options it doesn't understand to the linker, using -Wl.

Or if you insist on doing it the hard way look at the output of gfortran --verbose main.o -o main.exe

I have managed to do what i want. I will post an answer as a manual for future use within a few days. I want to try -W1 option and link with gfortran itself.

With the help of replies I have managed to do what I want.
I will post an instruction. Let it be the manual for future.
So there is Fortran subroutine which must be compiled to DLL
under Windows and called from Visual Studio C++.
The code for demo subroutine is:
SUBROUTINE TEST_SUB(X,Y)
  REAL X
  REAL Y
  COMPLEX Zi
  COMPLEX Zo
  Y = ABS(X + 1)
  Zo = CABS(Zi + 1)
  RETURN
  END

I went a more complicated way just to find out more about fortran infrastructure.
First compile into shared object.
gfortran -c main_sub.f -o main_sub.o 

Next link to produce DLL.
Here comes the problem. Additional libraries must be linked. Because subroutine uses
non intrinsic CABS function.
So I was using Notepad++ to do search for cabs function through all *.a files.
And like mentioned in answers I was using gfortran -verbose option on a fortran program
to see what does it passes to linker. Because gfortran is a ld linker frontend.
So i found out that libmingwex and libmsvcrt libraries must be linked.
That revealed in the following command
ld -shared -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Octave/Octave-8.3.0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/"  --export-all-symbols --output-def "main_sub.def"  -o "main_sub.dll" "main_sub.o" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Octave/Octave-8.3.0/mingw32/lib"  -lmingwex -lmsvcrt

libgfortran is not needed.
This produces DLL file with a function which can be called with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.
PS: I understand there is a way to make everyting in one call to gfrotran using -WL
option to pass all linker commands to linker. But I am very poor command line user.
By the way running linker with -L option but using backslashes for path causes error.
That made me crasy for one hour. Until I intuitevly changed backslashed to forward slahes in L option path. Backslashes for -o option and input file are ok.
Thanks to all for help!!
